# Iframe not showing in react native video component

Tags: android, api, react-native

I have an api, which I get an Iframe attribute from to display a video, the Iframe attribute comes in this form `"<iframe src=\"https://iframe.dacast.com/b/114063/c/477044\"  width=\"960\" height=\"540 frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>"` from the api, when I set it as the uri of the Video component it doesn't show the video, please what may i be doing wrong and how can I solve the issue. I am test running the application on an android device, the poster image just shows and nothing happens next.

Below is my React native code

```
   renderVideo () {
   const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
   return(
    <Video
      source={{uri: 'https://api.test.com/v3/channel/490909/embed/iframe?apikey=0000'}}
      controls={true}
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '80%' }}
      poster={params.image}
      posterResizeMode={'contain'}
   //   repeat={true}
      resizeMode={"cover"}
      minLoadRetryCount={5}
      volume={1.0}
      rate={1.0}
    //  fullscreen={true}
      ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}

    />
  )
  }

  render () {
   return (
  <View>
    {this.renderVideo()}
  </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi did you find any solution